# LIKE Search, German Umlaut and $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm developing a LIKE search a la google (search while typing). It's working fine, i.e. the results show up in an overlay div using JQuery, AJAX and the POST method. Now, when the user hits enter, the search form is submitted using the POST method as well, and a separate page is loaded which includes the same PHP-file that is used to generate the search results using AJAX.

I would thus expect the results to be the same. The file reads in both cases $_POST['searchstring'] into a variable and add slashes.

However, when the searchstring contains german Umlaute (ä,ö,ü) there are a lot of results on the separate search page not related to the actual searchstring, while in the AJAX overlay search the results are just as expected.

I suspect it has to do with encoding, but I don't seem to be able to narrow the source down further. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Try passing the UTF-8 encoding before your query. 9 times out of 10, it works.

Comment: In this type of scenario, I use my "allowed_chars" strategy, i.e. I have a set of characters that I actually deal with (but user can enter anything - I don't restrict that) so  at the backend, I simply check each character to ensure that it is in my allowed_chars array. It is easier so.

Comment: Fred: I guess passing utf8 is already done when instantiating the DB connection. I pass the charset then. Is this what you suggest? -- Good thought, emmanuel. Will keep that in mind. -- Meanwhile I have found another workaround solution. I submit the form using GET and copy the searchstring from GET to POST. Probably not elegant but seems to work for now.

Comment: Something like `mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);` or `$con->set_charset("utf8");` depending on the connection API, to be placed just before your query. There is a PDO equivalent also. Or, and for example `$content = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1252//TRANSLIT", $content);`

Comment: Yes, I do a similar thing for my PDO connection.

Comment: Check to see if both files are indeed saved as UTF-8 encoded and without BOM.